# Mapping an ImmutableJS collection

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an ImmutableJS structure that looks like this:

```
let state = fromJS({
  // ...
  foo: [{
    bar: ['id1', 'id2']
  },{
    bar: ['id2', 'id3']
  }]
});
```

I want to map over `foo` and for each item, filter the associated `bar` against another array of ids to exclude (`idsToExclude`).

I have come up with this:

```
const idsToExclude = ['id3', 'id4'];
state = { 
    ...state, 
    foo: state.get('foo').map((i) => 
        i.set(['bar'], i.get(['bar']
            .filterNot(b => idsToExclude.some(id => id === b)))) 
};
```

Is there a better, more idiomatic or terser way?

I ask because this seems quite verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get this a little cleaner by using [`.update`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/update), though this is still fairly long. You can also simplify `.some(id => id === b)` to `.contains(b)`.

```
state = state.update('foo', foo => 
    foo.map(item => 
        item.update('bar', 
            bar => bar.filterNot(
                id => idsToExclude.contains(id)))));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your existing code:

- `state = {...state}` is creating a plain JS object, not an Immutable.js `Map`, and it won't merge the new `foo` into the fields from `state` correctly.
- I'm pretty sure `get` and `set` only accept a single `key`, not an array.  To use an array of keys as a path, use `getIn` or `setIn`.

If you can use immutable `Set`s in your data structure instead of `Lists`, then you can use set operations like `subtract` to simplify your code:

```
import {fromJS, Set} from 'immutable'

const initState = fromJS({
  // ...
  foo: [
    {bar: Set(['id1', 'id2'])},
    {bar: Set(['id2', 'id3'])}
  ]
})
const idsToExclude = fromJS(['id3', 'id4'])
const finalState = initState.update('foo', foo =>
  foo.map(element =>
    element.update('bar', set =>
      set.subtract(idsToExclude)
    )
  )
)
```

Even if not storing `Set`s in your data structure, you could use them temporarily during the mutation:

```
const initState = fromJS({
  // ...
  foo: [
    {bar: ['id1', 'id2']},
    {bar: ['id2', 'id3']}
  ]
})
const idsToExclude = fromJS(['id3', 'id4'])
const finalState = initState.update('foo', foo =>
  foo.map(element =>
    element.update('bar', list =>
      list.toSet().subtract(idsToExclude).toList()
    )
  )
)
```